# How to work with Starscream library in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, websocket, uikit, starscream

I took this piece of code from an example of creating a WebSocket connection with the Starscream library based on UIKit. How can I make it work in my SwiftUI project?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {
    var socket: WebSocket!
    var isConnected: Bool = false
    let server = WebSocketServer()
    var token: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://-----")!)
        request.timeoutInterval = 5
        request.setValue("https://-----", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
        socket = WebSocket(request: request)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }   
    func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
        switch event {
        case .connected(let headers):
            isConnected = true
            print("websocket is connected: (headers)")
        case .disconnected(let reason, let code):
            isConnected = false
            print("websocket is disconnected: (reason) with code: (code)")
        case .text(let string):
            if string.contains("token expiring") { print("expiring"); socket.disconnect() }
            print("Received text: (string)")
        case .binary(let data):
            print("Received data: (data.count)")
        case .ping(_):
            break
        case .pong(_):
            break
        case .viabilityChanged(_):
            break
        case .reconnectSuggested(_):
            break
        case .cancelled:
            isConnected = false
        case .error(let error):
            isConnected = false
            handleError(error)
        }     }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: What does this code have to do with UI? I don’t see a single thing that is affected.

Comment: @loremipsum If I just copy and paste it into my SwiftUI project, nothing works. I don't know what I need to change or add to this code

Comment: @NiravD take a look at the answer from below

Comment: @TopScrech none of this code is affecting UI, SwiftUI is for UI. Just remove the UIViewController and adjust the viewDidLoad and you get working code. Where is the UI?

Comment: @loremipsum https://share.icloud.com/photos/042YNk1jxAbfq6WjoKxvMKoeg

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping the delegate in an `ObservableObject` class:

```
// Change Class Name to Websocket or WebsocketManager instead of WebSocket.
class Websocket: NSObject, WebSocketDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var socket: WebSocket!
    @Published var event: WebSocketEvent?
    var isConnected: Bool = false
    let server = WebSocketServer()
    var token: String = ""
    func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
        self.event = event
    }
    func connect(request: URLRequest) {
        socket = WebSocket(request: request)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }
}
```

And then in your `View`:

```
struct YourView: View {
    @StateObject var socketDelegate = Websocket()
    var body: some View {
        //your view
            .onAppear {
                var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://-----")!)
                request.timeoutInterval = 5
                request.setValue("https://-----", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
                socketDelegate.connect(request: request)
            }.onChange(of: socketDelegate.event) { event in
                switch event {
                case .connected(let headers):
                    isConnected = true
                    print("websocket is connected: (headers)")
                case .disconnected(let reason, let code):
                    isConnected = false
                    print("websocket is disconnected: (reason) with code: (code)")
                case .text(let string):
                    if string.contains("token expiring") { print("expiring"); socket.disconnect() }
                    print("Received text: (string)")
                case .binary(let data):
                    print("Received data: (data.count)")
                case .ping(_):
                    break
                case .pong(_):
                    break
                case .viabilityChanged(_):
                    break
                case .reconnectSuggested(_):
                    break
                case .cancelled:
                    isConnected = false
                case .error(let error):
                    isConnected = false
                    handleError(error)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Change the class name to `Websocket` or `WebsocketManager` as `WebSocket` is already used by the Starscream library. Check if this solves your error.

Comment: It throws a couple of errors 
https://share.icloud.com/photos/042YNk1jxAbfq6WjoKxvMKoeg